# Use the argmax of one data group to get the corresponding data of another group

Tags: python, pandas, python-xarray

#### Descriptions

The `ds` Dataset has two DataArrays: `test1` and `test2`.

`test1` is grouped by `x` and the maximum is obtained by `argmax`.

I want to use the index to get the corresponding location data of `test2`.

But, I don't know the correct method.

#### Example

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

ds = xr.Dataset(
    {"test1": (("x"), np.array([0, 1, 3, 2])),
     "test2": (("x"), np.array([2, 1, 3, 4]))},
    coords={"x": [10, 10, 20, 20]},
)


max_id = ds['test1'].groupby('x').apply(lambda da: da.argmax(dim='x'))
```

The method of getting the index of maximum of `test1` DataArray in each `x` group works well:

```
$ print(max_id)

<xarray.DataArray 'test1' (x: 2)>
array([1, 0])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) int64 10 20
```

I tried to use the `max_id` to subset the `test2` grouped by `x`:

```
test2_max = ds['test2'].groupby('x').apply(lambda da: da.isel(x=max_id.values))
```

But, it apply the selection to each `x` group of `test2`

```
$ print(test2_max)

<xarray.DataArray 'test2' (x: 4)>
array([1, 2, 4, 3])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) int64 10 10 20 20
```

#### Expected result

```
$ print(test2_max)

<xarray.DataArray 'test2' (x: 2)>
array([1, 3])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) int64 10 20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was playing around with this and I was able to do the following:

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

ds = xr.Dataset(
    {"test1": (("x"), np.array([0, 1, 3, 2])),
     "test2": (("x"), np.array([1, 2, 4, 3]))},
    coords={"x": [10, 10, 20, 20]},
)

test2_max = ds.groupby('x').apply(lambda ds: ds['test2'].isel(x=ds['test1'].argmax(dim='x')))
```

Output:

```
xarray.DataArray'test2'x: 2
array([2, 4])
Coordinates:
x
(x)
int64
10 20
Attributes: (0)
```

I have never worked with xarray, so don't know if other more efficient ways of do it exists

Comment: You method would get the maximum of `test2` in each `x` group. However, I want to get the data of `test2` at the index of `test1` maximum. If you change `test2` to `np.array([2, 1, 3, 4])`, you can see the effect. I updated the array values in the question now, in case someone misunderstands it.

Comment: I find the solution by myself now: `ds.groupby('x').apply(lambda ds: ds['test2'].isel(x=ds['test1'].argmax(dim='x')))`. You can add test it and add to your answer ;)